# Terraform cannot use target_id with for_each loop

Tags: azure, foreach, terraform, azure-diagnostics

We have this code for Storage Accounts creation:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "storage_account_shares" {
  for_each             = var.storage_share
  name                 = each.value["name"]
  storage_account_name = replace("${var.resource_name_prefix}${each.value["account_name"]}", "-", "")
  quota                = each.value["quota"]
  enabled_protocol     = each.value["protocol"]
}
```

Now I need to create diagnostic settings for each storage_share:

```
    resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "storagemain_logs" {
  for_each             = var.storage_share
  name       = "storagemain-logs"

  target_resource_id = azurerm_storage_share.storage_account_shares.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage_accounts.id

  dynamic "log" {
    iterator = entry
    for_each = local.storages_categories
    content {
        category = entry.value
        enabled  = true

        retention_policy {
            enabled = true
            days = 30
        }
    }
```

I don't understand what I should put in "target_resourse_id" to have it interactively work with "for_each" block that I have in storage_share resource. I tried this variant, but it didn't work:

```
locals {
  storage_accounts_output = {
    id   = [for i in azurerm_storage_share.storage_account_shares : i.id]
  }
}
```

and then added `target_resource_id = local.storage_accounts_output.id[index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `each.key` value to [refer to instances](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances) of `storage_account_shares` resources, like this:

```
target_resource_id = azurerm_storage_share.storage_account_shares[each.key].id
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the for_each chaining method described in [the official documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources) by modifying your code to look like this:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "storagemain_logs" {
  for_each   = azurerm_storage_share.storage_account_shares
  name       = "storagemain-logs"

  target_resource_id = each.value.id
```